# Akka Multi Node Testing available in Java?

Tags: integration-testing, akka

I have read the Akka Java documentation about [Multi Node Testing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/dev/multi-node-testing.html), however all codes are in Scala. Is there any reason for that? Google search was unsuccessful as well.

EDIT:
To reduce the tumbleweedness of this question, I did try :). A simple translation to Java of the existing Scala codes migth look like this:

```java
public class ClusterTest {

    protected RoleName first;

    @Test
    public void SimpleClusterListenerClusterJoinTest() throws Exception {
        new MultiNodeSpec(new MultiNodeConfig() {{
            first = this.role("first");
            second = this.role("second");
            third = this.role("third");
            this.commonConfig(ConfigFactory.parseString(
                "akka.crdt.convergent.leveldb.destroy-on-shutdown = on\n" +
                    "akka.actor.provider = akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider\n" +
                "akka.cluster.auto-join = off\n" +
                "akka.cluster.auto-down = on\n" +
                "akka.loggers = [\"akka.testkit.TestEventListener\"]\n" +
                "akka.loglevel = INFO\n" +
                "akka.remote.log-remote-lifecycle-events = off")); }}) {
                    {
                        Address firstAddress = node(first).address();
                        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
                        ArrayList<RoleName> firstnode = new ArrayList<RoleName>() {{
                        add(first);
                        }};
                        Seq<RoleName> fisrtnodeseq = (Seq<RoleName>)JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(firstnode).toList();                      
                        runOn(fisrtnodeseq, null);

                Cluster cluster = new Cluster((ExtendedActorSystem) system());
                cluster.join(firstAddress);
                // verify that single node becomes member
                cluster.subscribe(testActor(), MemberEvent.class);
                expectMsg(MemberUp.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int initialParticipants() {
                        return roles().size();
                    }};

    }

}
```

HOWEVER During the run with the arguments:
`-Dmultinode.max-nodes=4 -Dmultinode.host=127.0.0.1` etc. according to [Multi Node Testing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/dev/multi-node-testing.html) (if I list here all of the arguments the editor heavily complains :[ ) I will get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ActorSystem name [ClusterTest_2], must contain only word characters (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9] plus non-leading '-')
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:497)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
at akka.remote.testkit.MultiNodeSpec.<init>(MultiNodeSpec.scala:252)
at com.akkamint.demo.ClusterTest$2.<init>(ClusterTest.java:51)
```

is the internally generated ActorSystem name wrong?

Besides this I have two questions:

1. How can access the gossips from Java as in the Scala code,

   ```
   awaitCond(Cluster(system).latestGossip.members.exists(m ⇒ m.address == firstAddress && m.status == Up))
   ```

   and I have not found any way to implement the same in Java. My workaround is to subscribe to member events (see above), otherwise I do not know, is this effectively the same or not?
2. Thunk function (the second argument of runOn method)? What is that? How can use it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution by any chance?

Comment: I moved on, there was no solution. The scheduled corrections in the codebase were just too far (regarding the ActorSystem name bug). However, this question is rather old, so in the meantime, it might be corrected, I was not checking back.